# web servise & data binding with WP7

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, data-binding, query-string

I want to display a list of friends, and when i select a friend my app will navigate to another page showing this informations related to this friend.
I'm trying to read data using web service and display some of it(name and photo) on a costumized lisBox, and store some (id) temporarily in a list or collection that i can call it after and use it in my url:

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MyApp;component/FriendDetails.xaml?id{0}",friend_id, UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebService` to query the api and you need to add a "download callback" in that callback use linq to write the result of the query to an observable collection of an object matching the data you want from the result.

like this.

```
    friends = new ObservableCollection<Friend>();
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.OpenReadCompleted += Feed;
    wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(friendsURL));
}

private void Feed(object Sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Error != null){
      return;
   }

   using (Stream s = e.result){

      XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(s);
```

then use Linq to cycle through the data and add it your observablecollection of friends.